# Is there any to create static page ( html ) on which theme styles are not applied in wordpress

Tags: php, css, wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages

I want to make amp based static page like html but whenever i put that in wordpress,
wordpress applies its theme styles and settings

I want that it should not be affected by wordpress atleast not any theme based css or javascript

Thank you all

there must be a better way to do this please help
Thanks again

Comment: How do you add your static page? Just putting the html file in the wordpress root dir?

Answer (score 0):

### You are looking for Page templates.

> Page templates are a specific type of template file that can be applied to a specific page or groups of pages.

You can refer to @ https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/template-files-section/page-template-files/

In short, you can create a new page template `page-{slug}.php` (save at root). We then need to tell WordPress that this new file is a "template". We can do so through a comment header (bellow is a minimal version of it). You would probably need to include the theme header and footer too.

```
<?php

/*
 * Template Name: My new template title
*/

get_header();

// Page code here...

get_footer();
```

Answer (score 0):

You could create a dedicated PHP template file for that page, which you only assign to that particular page, and which does *not* contain the `get_header()` function.

Since besides not calling the theme stylesheet/s, this will also exclude a lot of other (necessary) functions, you could create a copy of your `header.php` file (in a child theme, if the theme isn't yours) which contains all the necessary functions and links *except* the link to the theme stylesheet, and call that "alternative header" file in your template for that page instead of using `get_header()`.